# How can I switch views programmatically in a view controller? (Xcode, iPhone)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, storyboard

Have been struggling with this for a while, and can never seem to get a direct answer.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you're in a Navigation Controller:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

or if you just want to present a new view:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];    
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Just to note that `presentModalViewController:animated:` has been marked as deprecated in the [UIViewController docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). `presentViewController:animated:completion:` should be used instead.

Comment: I am just at this question , if I use the second solution will I be able to go back to the previous view , and how ?

Comment: Needless to say, you now rarely instantiate view controllers by calling `alloc` and `init`. With storyboards, you use `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier@:"storyboard id"]`. Or if using storyboards with segue, you'd just perform segue directly with `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"storyboard id" sender:self];`, which will both instantiate new view controller and transition to it in one fell swoop. And if using NIBs, if the NIB name is different, you'd instantiate view controller with `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nibname" owner:self options:nil]`.

Comment: @Rob.  The line code  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier@:"storyboard id"];      execute multiple times then new *vc object created every time? what about earlier *vc object ? is this memory leak?

Comment: Yes, each time it would create new instance. Earlier instances would persist until you dismiss/pop them off the stack.

Answer (score 33):

If you want to present a new view in the same storyboard,

In CurrentViewController.m,

```
#import "YourViewController.h"

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *viewController = (YourViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To set identifier to a view controller,
Open MainStoryBoard.storyboard.
Select YourViewController
View-> Utilities -> ShowIdentityInspector.
There you can specify the identifier.

Comment: This pushes continous views as long as I press a row in a DynamicTableView cell, for example:
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329723/ipad-masterdetail-template

Comment: ok, if the story board is called Main.Storyboard, you need to put just @"Main", instead of @"Main.storyboard"

Answer (score 18):

**Swift** version:

**If you are in a Navigation Controller:**

```
let viewController: ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC") as ViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

**Or if you just want to present a new view:**

```
let viewController: ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC") as ViewController
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 17):

The `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is the `Storyboard ID`.

```
NextViewController *NVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextViewController"];
[self presentViewController:NVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 5):

To dismiss the Viewcontroller called with the previous answers code by CmdSft

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];    
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

you can use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.0 Version**

if you want to present new controller.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "controllerIdentifier") as! YourController
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and if you want to push to another controller (if it is in navigation)

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "controllerIdentifier") as! YourController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Identifier = Storyboard ID.

To set the Identifier, select the view controller in the storyboard > Identity inspector > Storyboard ID under Identity.

Answer (score 3):

```
#import "YourViewController.h"
```

To push a view including the navigation bar and/or tab bar:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboard" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *viewController = (YourViewcontroller *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

To set identifier to a view controller, Open YourStoryboard.storyboard. Select YourViewController View-> Utilities -> ShowIdentityInspector. There you can specify the identifier.

Comment: Last sentence does not apply to Xcode 10 due to UX changes.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
NSTimer *switchTo = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
           target:selfselector:@selector(switchToTimer)userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void) switchToTimer {
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerID"]; // Storyboard ID
[self presentViewController:vc animated:FALSE completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: This does not work for me, does it matter that im doing it in the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0 in**

one view controller to secondviewcontroller go:

```
let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MsgViewController") as! MsgViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
```

2nd viewcontroller to 1stviewcontroller(back)for: **back button on action event:-**

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:true)
```

3rdviewcontroller to 1st viewcontroller jump for

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated:true)
```

and most important storyboard in navigation bar unclicked make sure than this back action perform

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is asking how to swap a VIEW without changing viewCONTROLLERs. Am I misunderstanding his question?

In pseudocode, he wants to do:

```
let myController = instantiate(someParentController)

let view1 = Bundle.main.loadNib(....) as... blah
myController.setThisViewTo( view1 )

let view2 = Bundle.main.loadNib(....) as... blah
myController.setThisViewTo( view2 )
```

Am I getting his question wrong?