# Ipad MasterDetail Template

Tags: ipad

I have a question:

I am on a MasterDetail ipad template, Xcode42 in OSX1068 and loading my MasterDetail with a DYNAMIC tableview data source.

The table´s cell is linked by a Push segue to the DetailView, destination = Detail Split.
My problem is that the DetailViewController keeps looping on load a choice. Here is the code:

In MasterViewController:

```
    #pragma mark – Table view delegate
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    self.detailViewController.detailItem =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You choose %@",[_myList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    //
    -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
    // create an instance of DetailView
    DetailViewController *dVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    //sets dVC to the destinationViewController property of the segue
    dVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    //create the index path object
    NSIndexPath * path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString * theItem = [_myList objectAtIndex:path.row];
    dVC.rowNumber = path.row;
    dVC.itemName = theItem;
    }
```

And on DetailViewController.h:

```
    // tracking the items in the table
    @property int rowNumber;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * itemName;
```

Nothing fancy anywhere else.
Thanks for any help !

Comment: I managed to get it somewhat working with:
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    NextViewController *nvc = (NextViewController *)[mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextVC"];
    [_detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:nvc animated:YES];
     }else if(indexPath.row == 1){//another VC here...
    }
}`

Comment: But the problem is now that every cell´s call for another view stack them up !
I need to reset the cell value but int rowNumber = indexPath.row; is not working.
Thanks for any help !

Comment: This solution is also not working:
`        //
        DetailViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainStoryboard"];
        [self presentViewController:dvc animated:YES completion:nil]; `

Comment: Adding this line WORKS... but only in portrait modus:
  `    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *nvc =[mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextVC"];
        [_detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:nvc animated:YES];
        // the magic line ?
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = [_fruits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: And the short version:
`        [_detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextVC"] animated:YES];`

Comment: My state by now, somewhat working:
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { DetailViewController *mainVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
if (indexPath.row == 0) { MusicViewController *mVC = [[MusicViewController alloc] init]; mVC = [self.storyboard
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"musicVC"]; [_detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:(UIViewController *)mVC animated:YES];
[mainVC.navigationController setViewControllers: [NSArray arrayWithObject:mVC] animated: YES]; }else...`