# ios 9 QLPreviewController done button is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ios9

I'm using document handler in my project(cordova project) and it opens qlpreviewcontroller to open pdf docs

till IOS8 it is working fine and the previw controller is showing done button when preview opens.

In IOS9 done button is not showing.

I'm not too familiar with objective-c, any help appreaciated

my documenthandler code in the following gist

https://gist.github.com/sasikanth513/904ef8d4b7602c67dafa

Comment: why are you creating a button and then adding a dismiis action to it? You can do push instead of presenting a view controller

Comment: @Mr.T thank you so much for reply, small code snippet or new gist will be awesome as I'm not aware of objective-c much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933939/how-to-switch-views-programmatically-in-a-viewcontroller-xcode-iphone